# How to correctly receive and pass data in Angular to the back-end

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest

I'm new to Angular.I'm developing a system for learning purposes.It allows some one to make bookings on flights.I used Spring Boot as back-end  and Angular as front-end.I was able to create a form and submit that data correctly to the back-end and save that data in the database.

booking.ts model class

```js
export class Bookings{
    departure:number;
    arrival:string;
    departd:string;
    returnd:string;
    classtype:string;
    adults:number;
    children:number;
    infants:number;
}
```

booking.component.ts file

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking',
  templateUrl: './booking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking.component.css']
})
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  public minDate: Date = new Date ("01/01/2000 00:00 AM");
  public maxDate: Date = new Date ("01/01/2050 00:00 AM");
  public dateValue: Date = new Date ("01/01/2015 00:00 AM");

  booking:Bookings =new Bookings();
  
  message:Observable<Object>;

  constructor(private flightService:FlightService, private router: Router) { }

  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.flightService.search(this.booking).subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error)));
    this.booking = new Bookings();
    this.bookingData();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.save();    
  }

  bookingData() {
    this.router.navigate(['/bookings']);
  }

}
```

flight.service.ts file

```js
export class FlightService {

  private baseUrl='http://localhost:8080/flight/bookings';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getDestinations(): Observable<Destination[]>{
    return  this.http.get<Destination[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }

  search(booking: Object): Observable<Object> {
   return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, booking);
  }
  
}
```

As I mentioned as earlier the data was saved correctly in the DB with the help of SpringBoot back-end

But what I want to do is in the back end, is take those Booking data and search whether a flight matching their search exists.If exists I just want to show a message as "There is a flight that matches you" and if not display a message that "No matching Flight".So what I did was did the searching at the back-end and try to return a message as a String.
But I'm stuck at that point.I don't have an idea how to receive that String message.I know that through a Get request from the front end service I can receive that message.But is there a way to receive that message at the "search" post method in the FlightService. I think that it is not good to write a separate  post method to send that data and separate get method to receive that message.

Please help me and suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Why are you using post method for searching the results? You must use GET for that.

Comment: @GovindSinghThakur it doesn't have to be GET. Some use POST becuase of the GET length limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PostMapping("/bookings")
public ResponseEntity<String> bookings() {
    if(flight match found) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("There is a flight that matches you");
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("No matching Flight");
    }
}
```

This way you can get message as a string in response.

Comment: @BenSV please upvote if you get your answer otherwise let me know if anything is missing.